# Prove $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ is continuous at $0$ - proof assistance

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives, solution-verification

Define

$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
               \frac{\sin x}{x}, & \quad x \neq 0 \\
               1, & \quad x = 0 
       \end{cases} 
$$

Prove that $f$ is differentiable at $0$ and find $f'(0)$.

**Attempt**

I'm working through *Spivak's Calculus* and this question is being asked to me after I covered the Fundamental of Calculus and defining the $\sin$ and $\cos$ functions formally. I don't think it has much to do with that, but just as a caveat.

To prove the result I resorted to applying the definition that a function is differentiable at a point $c$. That is

> $f$ is differentiable at the point $0$ if  $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(0 + h) - f(0)}{h} = \text{some value}$.

Using this idea and some algebra I arrive at:

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\frac{\sin(h)}{h} - 1}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\sin(h) - h}{h^{2}}$$

I was expecting some simple cancellation of $h$ through out the expression, but alas that did not occur. I did think of using the idea that:

$$-\frac{1}{h} \leq \frac{\sin(h)}{h} \leq \frac{1}{h}$$,

but I don't see much coming from it. What step am I missing?

Comment: How are sine and cosine defined?  Are you allowed to use the Taylor series?

Comment: You have a typo in your last inequalities. Note that Spivak specifically tells you to use L'Hôpital's rule.

Comment: @TedShifrin, didn't even know this was specifically a Spivak question from the text. I took it from a set of handouts that I'm working along with in companion to the text. Do you know what question it is specifically in the text?

Comment: In the third/fourth edition, #3 in chapter 15.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use l'Hospital to obtain

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\sin(h) - h}{h^{2}}=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\cos(h) - 1}{2h}=0$$

indeed by definition of derivative

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac12\frac{\cos(h) - 1}{h}=-\frac12\sin (0)=0$$

Comment: Why did I not see the glaring L'Hopital, especially considering that the first part of the question asked me to shoe $f(x)$ is continuous and I used it then..... Thank you for the help.

Comment: @dc3rd Yes in this case we need that in order to avoid more complicated ways! You are welcome. Bye

Answer (score 2):

Using Taylor-Young expansion of $ \sin(h) $ around $ h=0 $, we get

$$\sin(h)=h-\frac{h^3}{6}(1+\epsilon(h))$$
with
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\epsilon(h)=0$$

thus

$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\sin(h)-h}{h^2}=\lim_{h\to 0}-\frac{h}{6}(1+\epsilon(h))=0$$

So, $ f $ is differentiable at $ x=0$ and $f'(0)=0$.